# Simple lack of understanding - MVC Routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-routing

I want to call a method in the controller. To do this, assuming default routing, I have to have a view that matches the controller I'm calling.

So if I have a contoller action

```
public ActionResult Edit(booking booking)
```

then I must have a view called Edit.

Is that right?

What I want to do is call any action in my controller from a given page without there being a view of the same name.

So if I'm on the Edit page, I should be able to call an action named createproduct, without there being a createproduct view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to have a view for every controller action. You can just call an action by calling the correct URL, that's one of the advantages of MVC and routing. Routes don't have to represent a physical location. You should be able to do the following `/Controller/Edit/booking`

Answer (score 0):

A controller action doesn't have to return a View. You tend to see the action method return View(), which renders a view with the same name as the action method by default. But you can return View("SomeOtherViewName"). You can also return various other results, such as FileResult (returns a file), HttpStatusCodeResult (returns an HTTP response code with no content), JsonResult (returns Json), Content (returns some string) etc. The Controller class has methods to help return some of these result types: File, Json, Content.